# Twitter whitelisted my application so I can retrieve user email, but still not getting it?

Tags: twitter-oauth, auth0

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and [React Native Lock](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock) (created and maintained by Auth0) to authenticate users through Google, Facebook, and Twitter.  Despite getting my app whitelisted by Twitter and adjusting my Twitter application permissions to request emails, I am not getting back an email in the raw JSON after a Twitter user authenticates.  Why?

**Twitter whitelisted permissions to retrieve email:**

[image: Twitter email whitelist so I can get user emails]

**React Native Lock code mostly taken from sample app:**

[image: React Native Lock Code]

**After logging in through Twitter, here is the raw JSON screenshot from Auth0 dashboard. No Twitter email.**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of today, `August 3rd 2016`, it appears that the Auth0 strategy that maps social provider profile information from Twitter to an Auth0 normalized user profile does not contain a mapping for `email` attribute.

Don't believe this has anything to do with `React Native`, `Lock`, or the `scope` information you provided (although you would not need to explicitly put in `email` as you have already declared `profile` which gives you everything).

You can reproduce it by going to the Auth0 Dashboard, and choosing `Connections -> Social -> Twitter` then hit the `Try` button.

Screenshots below:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Email is not provided. Believe this is a conscious choice (rather than a bug) specific to Twitter social connections usage with Auth0 as twitter requires you to make an additional request after login to get just the email.

For example, you could use an Auth0 Rule (available on the dashboard under `Rules -> Create Rule`). See screenshot below:

[image]

NOTE: For this rule to work, your Twitter application must be whitelisted to access email addresses. See the docs associated with this rule for details.

Comment: If it's a conscious choice, I do not understand why they have a sample rule specifically for getting a Twitter email.  See https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/rules/get-twitter-email.md

Comment: @nomad I wrote that rule - it's mainly a workaround to Auth0 not returning the email as part of the core profile. This is because Twitter requires an additional request after authentication to get the user's email (it is not returned as part of the regular user profile). As the comments in that rule mention, the email will be returned by the application but not persisted as part of the Auth0 user profile.

Comment: @nomad - please can you check above and if in agreement then mark answer as correct :)

Comment: @nomad - had another user asking same question - please can you mark this answer correct if you agree? It would help similar users identify the right answer.

Comment: It's not correct at all.  Auth0 has a rule specifically for getting the Twitter email so your post is misleading.  https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/rules/get-twitter-email.md

Comment: @RodrigoLópezDato the problem with your rule is that your team members who work on React Native Lock have decided not to support your rule.  They have stated that it's out of scope, which is a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/rules/get-twitter-email.md,

I got it to work with the following,

```
    function(user, context, callback) {
  // NOTE: For this rule to work, your Twitter application must be whitelisted to access email addresses.
  // See: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials
  //
  // If Twitter does not return an email address, this rule will cause authentication to fail.
  // This might not be the desired behavior, so make sure to adapt it to your requirements.
  //
  // Remember to set the TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY and TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET configuration variables.

  var request = require('request');
  var oauth = require('oauth-sign');

  if (context.connectionStrategy !== 'twitter') {
    return callback(null, user, context);
  }

  var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json';
  var params = {
    include_email: true,
    oauth_consumer_key: configuration.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_nonce: require('uuid').v4().replace(/-/g, ''),
    oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    oauth_timestamp: Date.now() / 1000 | 0,
    oauth_token: user.identities[0].access_token,
    oauth_version: '1.0',
  };

  params.oauth_signature = oauth.hmacsign(
      'GET',
      url,
      params,
      configuration.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      user.identities[0].access_token_secret
  );

  var auth = Object.keys(params).sort().map(function(k) {
    return k + '="' + oauth.rfc3986(params[k]) + '"';
  }).join(', ');

  request({
    url: url + '?include_email=true',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + auth
    }
  }, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200) {
      return callback(new Error('Error retrieving email from twitter: ' + body || err));
    }
    var result;
    try {
      result = JSON.parse(body);
    } catch (e) {
      return callback(new Error('Invalid JSON returned by Twitter'));
    }
    if (!result.email) {
      // Might not want to fail in this case
      return callback(new Error('Twitter did not return an email address'));
    } else {
      user.email = result.email;
      user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};
      // update the app_metadata that will be part of the response
      user.app_metadata.social_email = user.email;

      // persist the app_metadata update
      auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
      .then(function(){
        callback(null, user, context);
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        callback(err);
      });

      return callback(null, user, context);
    }
  });
}
```