# Spring Security Auth0 library throws error when Auth0 user is a Twitter social login

Tags: java, spring, twitter, auth0

Our server application uses the Spring Security Auth0 JAVA library to verify Java Web Tokens (JWTs). When the JWT is based on a user that used a social login through Twitter, the library throws a null pointer exception because the class Auth0UserInfo expects email_verified flag to exist in the JWT when email is present. I'm using an Auth0 rule to get the email via the Twitter api because Twitter does not give the email out. After this I try to add the flag email_verified = true in the same rule. I cannot add the email_verified flag to the user object in the rule because Auth0 seems to prevent it from being persisted. Is there a way to get both the email and the email_verified flag into the user object so that the jwt contains this information?

Comment: Hi Jon, I authored the library I believe you are referring to. Please can you point me at the relevant class (there is no Auth0UserInfo class). Can you please confirm you are using this repo, and using latest version? https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-security-mvc   I setup a local app using that library with a Twitter connection https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-mvc-sample  and had no issues. Not saying you do not have an issue, just that I could not reproduce. Also, I was unclear which Auth0 Rule you were referring to - any further info in question would be helpful.

Comment: Jon - are you still having difficulties? Please consider trying our `Get email address from Twitter` rule template.  On the auth0 dashboard just click on `Rules -> Create Rule -> Get email address from Twitter` and follow the instructions there. From your question, it wasn't clear whether your issue was with Rules or with the Java library you reference and state ` class Auth0UserInfo expects email_verified flag to exist in the JWT when email is present` - if you can clarify as per previous comment that would be great.

Comment: Jon - this answer may also help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/38736322/1882064